# Uploading images safely to my server

Tags: php

Currently, I check the image size, if it's null or size[0] or size[1] == 0, then I don't accept the image.

As well, I reconstruct the image and then chmod it over to a folder with limited permissions (0664)

However, this process takes a lot of time for large images because of reconstruction of the image. Is it safe enough to simply just check the image size and chmod it with limited permissions to another folder?

What other options do i have that won't take as long?

Comment: If you have control of the front end, you could resize the image and maybe convert the image to reduce the size (such as to JPEG). I would also check the MIME type. Why the reconstruction?

Comment: The reconstruction is just to make sure 100% it's a safe image. I need the image at the orginial size, although

Comment: I think the reconstruction is unnecessary, by limiting the MIME types it should be secure enough if you do it the right way.

Comment: Mime types are not really providing any security as they can easily be faked. Using `$imageinfo = getimagesize()` to validate that it's an image seems quite clever, instead of looking at the size you could investigate `$imageinfo[2] `and check the different image types defined by the system constants `IMAGETYPE_*`, see http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php for a full list of available constants.

Answer (score 0):

They can easily be faked if you check the type given by the browser, there are secure methods oft reading the MIME type